# How to get rid of duplicate entries in a comma separated string

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a comma separated string, how do i remove duplicate entries in the string in a pythonic way.

For example the string `"a,a,b"` should be changed to `"a,b"`.

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicates, or only duplicates next to one another? i.e., does 'a,b,a' stay the same or become 'a,b' (or, indeed, 'b,a')?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the order of elements important? If not, the easiest way is to create a `set`:

```
result = ','.join(set(text.split(',')))
```

But as I said, that won’t preserve the order of the original string:

```
>>> text = 'b,a,b'
>>> ','.join(set(text.split(',')))
'a,b'
```

Answer (score 7):

If the order is important, you can use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> s = "a,a,b"
>>> ",".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s.split(',')))
'a,b'
```

Note that this will also handle duplicates that are not next to each other:

```
>>> s = "a,b,a,a,a,b"
>>> ",".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s.split(',')))
'a,b'
```

Comment: Sorry ordering was not important to me, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
list(set(['a','a','b']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually haven't specified what you want well enough. As everyone has pointed out, does order matter? Do you want to remove all duplicates, or only strings of the same one?

If order doesn't matter, all of the `set` solutions are fine. If it does, there are [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for these cases:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse, imap, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

You can apply either of these to `'a,a,b'.split(',')`:

```
In [6]: ','.join(set('a,a,b'.split(',')))
Out[6]: 'a,b'

In [7]: ','.join(unique_justseen('a,a,b'.split(',')))
Out[7]: 'a,b'

In [8]: ','.join(unique_everseen('a,a,b'.split(',')))
Out[8]: 'a,b'
```

or, for a case where they are different:

```
In [9]: ','.join(set('a,a,b,a'.split(',')))
Out[9]: 'a,b'

In [10]: ','.join(unique_everseen('a,a,b,a'.split(',')))
Out[10]: 'a,b'

In [11]: ','.join(unique_justseen('a,a,b,a'.split(',')))
Out[11]: 'a,b,a'
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hey just use this Java 8 Syntax:***

```
 String words = "hello,hii,hii,bye,hii,word,World";
        words = Arrays.stream(words.split(",")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

**Output:**

```
words: hello,hii,bye,word,World
```